# reading shp file with pyshp jupyter

Tags: record, shapefile, pyshp

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import shapefile as shp

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
shp_path = 'seoul\seoul.shp'
sf = shp.Reader(shp_path)
sf.records()[1]
```

and then finally I got this error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 0: invalid start byte

I wanna how to solve this problem

Comment: could you add a example of your `seoul.shp`?

Comment: print(sf.fields[1])

['emd_cd', 'C', 10, 0]

Comment: there is sf.records which contains the record data of seoul

Comment: there is sf.shapes() which includes polygons of seoul administrative district

Answer (score 0):

You need to try different encodings options.
The [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/#reading-shapefiles) shows a way to do it for the shapefile's method Reader:

```
shp_path = "Barrios_Cali/Barrios.shp"
sf = shp.Reader(shp_path, encoding="latin1") # Notice the encoding option
```

So go ahead and look for the .shp probable encoding type and give it a try.